# How will you Ensure only one object of a class can be created

Tags: c#, oop, object

In an interview question, I was asked this question I replied that we can achieve this by having private constructor BUT Im not sure about it. Is it correct? I would like more explanation and other ways (if there are any) to achieve this.

Sorry If this sound dumb. Im actually learning OO Design so there is a lot of confusion

Comment: You implement the singleton pattern. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx - but I'd recommend against it, in terms of testability etc.

Comment: Is singleton same as having a private constructor?

Comment: There are other things to consider. For example, serialization. One has to be carefull to not end up with multiple singletons if a singleton is serializible.

Comment: If you're serializing a Singleton, yes, you have other things to consider.

Comment: There really not much relationship between private constructor and singleton... Private constructor only limits who can create instances of the type, but in no way limits number of instances.

Comment: A private constructor is the only way to prevent others from constructing an instance of said type. For a Singleton, in a language like c# or java, you need a static instance field, an initializer/accessor of that field, and a private ctor.

Comment: Will it be ok to say that you can create a static class where we have only one instance?

Comment: No, a static class has *no* instances. And if you're trying to learn good OO design, I really wouldn't get hung up on the singleton pattern at the moment - it's generally worth avoiding anyway.

Comment: @dwerner it's the standart approach,cbut not the only one.

Comment: @CodesInChaos what other suggestions do you have?

Comment: @dwerner Constructor parameters which an outsidee won't be able to provide, an abstract class with private nested concrete classes, walking the callstack, setting and unsetting a private thread-local flag, registering the global instance in the constructor and throwing on a second call... Much uglier than a private/internal constructor (it's the standard approach for good reason), but alternatives exist.

Comment: The correct answer to "How will you Ensure only one object of a class can be created" is "I won't as the singleton pattern is a code smell that should be avoided".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested to check for [singleton pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). Check the [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) by Jon Skeet about it.

> The singleton pattern is one of the best-known patterns in software
>   engineering. Essentially, a singleton is a class which only allows a
>   single instance of itself to be created, and usually gives simple
>   access to that instance.

Comment: Can you please give a simple code example from beginners point of view. Im struggling with singleton pattern

Comment: @Nuke:- Did you try to read the article which I have linked, its quite self explanatory.

Comment: @Nuke, please don't struggle with the singleton pattern, it's a code smell that leads all too easily to hard-to-test code, so you don't want to be using it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic implementation of a singleton:

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() { }
}
```

Due to the private constructor you cannot write this code:

```
Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

The compiler complains with:

> CS0122 'Singleton.Singleton()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

But you can easily get the single instance like this:

```
Singleton singleton = Singleton.Instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

A private constructor is only part of the answer. You'll also need a static instance of the same class, and a getInstance () method, returning that lazily initialised instance.

This question is intended to probe for knowledge of the Singleton pattern.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Why a "lazily initialised instance"?

Comment: Would you statically initialize it? If you have to have a global variable, which is what a Singleton amounts to, it's typically going to have run-time dependencies. If not, why initialize it if you never use it?

Comment: The .NET framework only initializes static variables when the class is first referenced. So if your code doesn't use the class the instance is not initialized.

Comment: Some singletons need lazy construction, others do not. In my experience the few cases where singletons are not bad design don't need lazy construction.

Answer (score 0):

A complete final solution for enforcing the Singleton pattern can be put forth with the following code, refer comments for the explanation.

```
public final class Singleton {

    // A private static variable of the class
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    // A private constructor so that - 
    // Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
    // the above line throws an exception
    private Singleton() {}

    // Finally, a private static method to get the instance 
    // of the class
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I'd save future visitors some of the same confusion that I just went through. I'll not go into great detail about the bits I was confused on, you'll probably spot them anyway. :)

C#

```
// Using your class name, not Singleton
public class MyClass
{
    // Public so the instance can be seen
    public static class MyClass _instance = new MyClass();
    // Private constructor so it doesn't create any more instances
    private MyClass() { }
    // The Public Property that intercepts the creation requests
    public MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance != null)
                return _instance; // Pass back the single instance already created
            else
            {
                MyClass _instance = new MyClass();
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create the rest of your class
    public int myInt;
    public string myString;
}

// Access it in your program
public MyClass myclass = MyClass._instance;

public Main()
{
    myclass.myString = "This is a string inside a Singleton instance of a class.";
    Console.WriteLine(myclass.myString);
}
```

EDIT: Found why it wasn't working. The static instance has to be public.